# Capture photo from camera is not working in Android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, photo-gallery

I used default camera of device for capture photo in my app. When I used android 10 and below version everything is working fine. but when I used camera in android 11 then not working in app. Can you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Since API level 30, there have been changes in the package visibility. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

For your package manager to work properly, you need to declare `<queries>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

Code:

```
<manifest package="your.package.name">
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

This works only for the default camera apps. If your app is using some 3rd party camera, you can find some info [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/16/action-image-capture-android-r.html).

Comment: Above code is not working in android 11.can you please help me about this issue.

Comment: hi @Sahil ,you can refer this [link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/788),It's very detailed.Hope this could help you with your issue

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest outside the application tag, I hope it will resolve your issue

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

**File sd_directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);**

to

**File sd_directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);**

Answer (score 1):

Android 11 has Storage update. So When using SDK >= 29 must set URI instead of File path.

```
URI uri = null;   // set this uri in camera Intent
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
           uri =  getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
        }
        else
        {
            uri =   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
        }
    }
```